# State is not getting initialized to the initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am new to the `react-redux`.

Now I have an object which is like ,

```
const initialState = {
        Low: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 0,
                technology: '',
                level: 'EASY'
            }
        ],
        Medium: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 0,
                technology: '',
                level: 'MEDIUM'
            }
        ],
        High: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 0,
                technology: '',
                level: 'TOUGH'
            }
        ]
    }

Now, 

    export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case QUIZ_DATA:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    Low: action.data,
                    error: false,
                } 
            case RESET_SETUP_QUIZ: {
            console.log("intial state is ",  ...state);
            return {
                ...state
            }
```

Now, here what happens is after some manipulations, this objects gets changes with every key is having some values. like,

So, This gets changed.

```
{
        Low: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 11,
                technology: 'xsxs',
                level: 'EASY'
            }
        ],
        Medium: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 22,
                technology: 'swwsw',
                level: 'MEDIUM'
            }
        ],
        High: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 110,
                technology: 'xsxsx',
                level: 'TOUGH'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now, what I want to do is that ,

When user clicks a button that time I want to change this to the initial state.

So that it will not have any values as it should be same as by default.

SO, what I tried it

```
return {
   initalState
}
```

But then I tried with the `object.assign`.

```
case QUIZ_DATA:
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    state,
    {
      Low: action.data,
      error: false
    }
  )
```

But still Here it copies only the first level of variables.

So, Still I am not able to do this .

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: First I noticed is that you're not returning anything for default condition of `action.type`. Return the state on `default:`. Second thing the return { ...state, low: action.data, error: false } should work right out of the box.
Is it possible to set up a failing example on codepen/fiddle somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Object.assign will not help with deep copy.

If you want to do deep copy use.

```
let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

here newObj will be deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

To reset to the initial state all you have to do is:

```
case RESET_SETUP_QUIZ: {
    return initialState;
```

That's it. When the reducer function is called after the first time, `state` will be the current state, not initial state.

Comment: In your question, you return `initialState` inside of an object, like this `return { initialState };` You just need to return `initialState`.

Comment: So, that is what I saying, I want to set it to the initial state once button is cliked

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, you will need to provide more information. What does your action look like. What happens when you dispatch it?

Comment: Hey, I have added after some manipulation my state has that data.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you're not returning anything for default condition of `action.type`. 
Return the state on `default:`. Second thing the `return { ...state, low: action.data, error: false }` should work right out of the box.

```
export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case QUIZ_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                Low: action.data,
                error: false,
            } 
        case RESET_SETUP_QUIZ: {
            console.log("intial state is ",  ...state);
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
case RESET_SETUP_QUIZ: {
        console.log("intial state is ",  ...state);
        return {
            initialState
        }
```

You should

```
case RESET_SETUP_QUIZ: {
        console.log("intial state is ", initialState);
        return initialState;
```

Or

```
 case RESET_SETUP_QUIZ: {
        console.log("intial state is ", initialState);
        return {
           ...initialState
        };
```